# Problem definition of struct in Macro

Tags: c, macros, struct, types, function-pointers

I'm working on macros in C, trying to simulate the objet behavior but using C and I'm having a problem with the definition of a variable defined from a struct in another struct in a macro. That's my code... it works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define STACK_MAX_CAPACITY 10
#define DECLARE_STACK(Type)                             \
    typedef struct MetaPile_##Type;                     \
                                                        \
    typedef struct Pile_##Type_t{                       \
        Type q[STACK_MAX_CAPACITY];                     \
        int pos;                                        \
    } Pile_##Type;                                      \
                                                        \
    typedef struct MetaPile_##Type_t{                   \
        void (* push) ( Pile_##Type* p, Type val );     \
        void (*init) (Pile_##Type* p);                  \
    } MetaPile_##Type;                                  \
                                                        \
    void init_##Type( Pile_##Type* p ){                 \
        p->pos = 0;                                     \
        int i;                                          \
        for(i=0; i<STACK_MAX_CAPACITY; i++){            \
            p->q[i]=0;                                  \
        }                                               \
    }                                                   \
                                                        \
    void push_##Type( Pile_##Type* p, Type val ) {      \
        if(p->pos < STACK_MAX_CAPACITY){                \
            p->q[p->pos]=val;                           \
            p->pos++;                                   \
        }                                               \
    }                                                   \
    MetaPile_##Type TheMetaPile_##Type;                 \
    void initTheMetaPile_##Type(){                      \
        TheMetaPile_##Type.init = &init_##Type;         \
        TheMetaPile_##Type.push = &push_##Type;         \
    }                                                   \
                                                        \

DECLARE_STACK(int)

int main(){

    int i;

    initTheMetaPile_int();
    Pile_int pi;

    TheMetaPile_int.init(&pi);

    push_int(&pi, 2);
    push_int(&pi, 3);
    push_int(&pi, 4);
    push_int(&pi, 5);
    push_int(&pi, 6);

    for(i=0; i<STACK_MAX_CAPACITY; i++){
        printf("%d",pi.q[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The first structure define an array of a dinamic type thanks to the macro (Pile_##Type) that represents the attributs side of an objet, and another structure (MetaPile_##Type) that will manage the "methods" of the objet, via fonction pointers. The fonction init works as a constructor and initialises my "objet" pi.

Now what I want is to have a reference in Pile_##Type of a variable of type MetaPile_##Type (called for exemple myClass) in order to be able to make pi->myClass->push and call the fonction push_int. But when I make:

```
typedef struct Pile_##Type_t{                       \
    Type q[STACK_MAX_CAPACITY];                     \
    int pos;                                        \
    MetaPile_##Type myClass;                        \
} Pile_##Type;                                      \
```

I have a misunderstandable mistake...

```
D:\main.c|40|warning: useless keyword or type name in empty declaration|
D:\main.c|40|error: syntax error before "MetaPile_int"|
D:\main.c|40|warning: no semicolon at end of struct or union|
D:\main.c|40|warning: type defaults to `int' in declaration of `Pile_int'|
D:\main.c|40|warning: data definition has no type or storage class|
D:\main.c|40|error: syntax error before '*' token|
D:\main.c|40|error: syntax error before '*' token|
D:\main.c|40|error: syntax error before '*' token|
D:\main.c||In function `init_int':|
D:\main.c|40|error: `p' undeclared (first use in this function)|
D:\main.c|40|error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once|
D:\main.c|40|error: for each function it appears in.)|
D:\main.c|40|error: syntax error before '*' token|
D:\main.c||In function `push_int':|
D:\main.c|40|error: `p' undeclared (first use in this function)|
D:\main.c|40|error: `val' undeclared (first use in this function)|
D:\main.c||In function `main':|
D:\main.c|47|error: syntax error before "pi"|
D:\main.c|49|error: `pi' undeclared (first use in this function)|
||=== Build finished: 12 errors, 4 warnings ===|
```

I don't know what's worong with the defintion of myClass, I've used * also but the error persits. Thanks if somebody can help.

Comment: Whoa, is that the C way of creating templates? Scary at least... :S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is not the usage of macros, this only distracts you.

```
typedef struct MetaPile_int;
```

is just syntactically incorrect. A simple forward declaration of a `struct` looks like this:

```
struct MetaPile_int;
```

But if you just want to make your life easier do it like this:

```
typedef struct MetaPile_int MetaPile_int;
```

This is a forward declaration of the `struct` and a definition of the identifier `MetaPile_int` at the same time.

To get it working try it without putting it in a macro, first. Or use a compiler that helps you trace errors in macros such as clang.

Comment: @Jens... Thanks!!! Yes you're right, actually I have some bad definitions of my structs in my code. I have changed them. As U said the forward declaration must be struct MetaPile##Type, and I must use the same struct MetaPile##Type syntax to define any variable of this type. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `typedef struct MetaPile_##Type;` line - what's that supposed to do (besides causing your errors, that is)?

Comment: @Erik... I did it but the error continues. Actually I think that I cannot remove this line because it's the forward declaration of the struct MetaPile_##Type; that is defined some lines after.

Comment: @jomaora: After removing that typedef, your code compiles without errors here. And, if you needed a forward declaration (you don't) you'd use `struct MetaPile_##Type_t;` not an incomplete typedef.

Comment: @Erik... It doesn't work here... :( removing or changing my definition to struct MetaPile_##Type_t;. :S

Comment: @jomaora: Your exact code, copy-pasted to test.c and compiled with gcc, works after removal of the typedef. Doublecheck your paste. Or, which compiler are you using?

Comment: @jomaora: Try copy-pasting the code from your post to a new file. If that works, you likely have some funny characters in your file (such as space after \ perhaps)

Answer (score 0):

You try to insert a full struct (`MetaPile_##Type`) before declaring it, change the order of them like that [ in `MetaPile_##Type` you only use pointers to `Pile_##Type_t`, and the size of pointers is known]:
*Edit:*
This declaration works for me fine:

```
#define DECLARE_STACK(Type)                             \
    struct Pile_##Type_t;                     \
                                                        \
    typedef struct MetaPile_##Type_t{                   \
        void (* push) ( Pile_##Type_t* p, Type val );     \
        void (*init) (Pile_##Type_t* p);                  \
    } MetaPile_##Type;                                  \
                                                        \
    typedef struct Pile_##Type_t{                       \
        Type q[STACK_MAX_CAPACITY];                     \
        int pos;                                        \
    MetaPile_##Type myClass;                        \
    } Pile_##Type;                                      \
                                                        \
    void init_##Type( Pile_##Type* p ){                 \
        p->pos = 0;                                     \
        int i;                                          \
        for(i=0; i<STACK_MAX_CAPACITY; i++){            \
            p->q[i]=0;                                  \
        }                                               \
    }                                                   \
                                                        \
    void push_##Type( Pile_##Type* p, Type val ) {      \
        if(p->pos < STACK_MAX_CAPACITY){                \
            p->q[p->pos]=val;                           \
            p->pos++;                                   \
        }                                               \
    }                                                   \
    MetaPile_##Type TheMetaPile_##Type;                 \
    void initTheMetaPile_##Type(){                      \
        TheMetaPile_##Type.init = &init_##Type;         \
        TheMetaPile_##Type.push = &push_##Type;         \
    }                                                   \
                                                        \
```

and it should do the work.

Comment: Hi @MByD, thanks. Well swaping the declarations the mistake stays. I'm adding a variable of MetaPile_##Type in Pile_##Type... I don't see that in your code.